# EJB QL Syntax error

Tags: java, exception, syntax, jpql, ejbql

In my app, I have the following 2 entities:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Commentable implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    protected Long id;
    protected long createdDate;
    ...
}

@Entity
public class Announcement extends Commentable implements Serializable { 

    private int    type;  
    private String title;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "MEDIUMTEXT")
    private String content;
    ...
}
```

When I try to get some rows from the Announcement table, I keep getting syntax error on the following line:

```
Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT A FROM Announcement A JOIN Commentable C ON A.id = C.id WHERE A.type=:type ORDER BY C.createdDate DESC");
```

This is the stacktrace:

```
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-8023] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing the query [SELECT A FROM Announcement A JOIN Commentable C ON A.id = C.id WHERE A.type=:type ORDER BY C.createdDate DESC].
Internal Exception: org.eclipse.persistence.internal.libraries.antlr.runtime.EarlyExitException
```

I'd be very grateful if you could tell me what I have done wrong here.

Best regards,
James Tran

Comment: Can you post the error stacks?

Comment: Could you edit you question to add the stack trace and the code of the entities Announcement and Commentable?

Comment: Can you post the two entity classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Announcement extends Commentable, you shouldn't need a join:

```
select a from Announcement a where a.type = :type order by a.createdDate desc
```

Comment: The problem is that I use `InheritanceType.JOINED`. Hence, the Announcement table will not have the column `createdDate`. I tried your solution earlier and GlassFish threw me the No Column SQLException.

Comment: @Mr.J4mes Is this perhaps a bug? EclipseLink should do the join, as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I messed up the creating table process earlier and it caused this problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `ON` clause in JPQL. It's not necessary because you can only join two entities that have an association between them, and the mapping of the association already contains the necessary information necessary to know on which columns the join must be made. So the following is sufficient:

```
SELECT a FROM Announcement a JOIN a.commentable c
WHERE a.type = :type ORDER BY c.createdDate DESC
```

This assumes that you have a ToOne association between `Announcement` and `Commentable`.

EDIT: Announcement extends Commentable. So you don't need any join. The JPA engine does the join for you (if a join is necessary, depending on the inheritance strategy):

```
SELECT a FROM Announcement a WHERE a.type = :type ORDER BY a.createdDate DESC
```

Comment: The problem is that the `Announcement` extends `Commentable`. I don't have any ToOne relationship in them.

Comment: The you don't need any join: an Announcement IS A Commentable. I'll edit my answer.